# Effective potential in Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, effective-field-theory, 1pi-effective-action

I have two question related to the steps in equations 3-7 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0104282):

**Question 1** They find the effective potential in eq. (5) as the negative of the effective Lagrangian (eq. (3)). I don't see how they go from eq. (3) to (5). Can anybody give a hint on how to approach this?

They start with the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{f_{\pi}^2}{4} \mathrm{Tr} [ \nabla_{\mu}U\nabla^{\mu}U^{\dagger} + 2 m_{\pi}^2 \mathrm{Re} U ]$$

with the covariant derivative being

$$\nabla_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu}U + i\frac{\mu_I}{2}[U,\tau_3]$$

in this Lagrangian, we can look past the $\partial_{\mu}U$ part as they explain in the paper.

They get to the effective potential:

$$V_{eff}(U) = \frac{f_{\pi}^{2}\mu_{I}^{2}}{8} \mathrm{Tr} (\tau_3 U \tau_3 U^{\dagger}-1)-\frac{f_{\pi}^{2}m_{\pi}^{2}}{2} \mathrm{Re} \ \mathrm{Tr}(U)$$

**Question 2** If one has come to eq. (5) they afterwards insert eq. (6) to obtain eq. (7). I get something similar, but somewherev i must have missed something obvious. What i have is:

$$V_{eff}(U)=\underbrace{\frac{f_{\pi}^{2}\mu^{2}_{I}}{8} \mathrm{Tr}(\tau_3 U \tau_3 U^{\dagger}-1)}_{term \ A} - \underbrace{\frac{f_{\pi}^{2}m^{2}_{\pi}}{2} \mathrm{Re \ Tr} \ U}_{term \ B} \\$$

Upon inserting their ansatz: $\Big[U = cos \ \alpha + i \tau_1 cos \ \phi \ sin \ \alpha + i\ \tau_2 \ sin\ \phi \ sin \ \alpha \Big]$ i get:

in term B the only surviving part is $2 cos \ \alpha$ since this is real, so we get $$f_{\pi}^{2}m^{2}_{\pi} cos \ \alpha$$

which is fine, they get the same result. So far so good.

in term A i get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{f_{\pi}^{2}\mu^{2}_{I}}{8} \mathrm{Tr} \Big[ \tau_3 \{ cos \ \alpha\ \mathbb{1} + i \tau_1 cos \ \phi \ sin \ \alpha + i\ \tau_2 \ sin\ \phi \ sin \ \alpha \} \\ \tau_3 \ \{ cos \ \alpha\ \mathbb{1} - i \tau_1 cos \ \phi \ sin \ \alpha - i\ \tau_2 \ sin\ \phi \ sin \ \alpha \} - \mathbb{1} \Big]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
i have inserted the identity matrix in the terms to make everything explicit. All terms where $\tau_a \tau_b$ mix with $a \neq b$ vanishes so what we have left is:

\begin{equation}
\frac{f_{\pi}^{2}\mu^{2}_{I}}{8} \mathrm{Tr} [\tau_3 \ cos \ \alpha \ \tau_3 \ cos \ \alpha] = \frac{f_{\pi}^{2}\mu^{2}_{I}}{8} \ 2 \ cos^2 \alpha - 2 = \frac{f_{\pi}^{2}\mu^{2}_{I}}{4} \ (\frac{1}{2}cos(2 \ \alpha)-1)
\end{equation}

Where in the last stap i have just used the trigonometric identity, but i get the wrong denomintor doesn't match theirs. Mine is still 8 while theirs has lowered to 4 ???

For reference they get:

$$V_{eff}(\alpha) = \frac{f_{\pi}^{2}\mu^{2}_{I}}{4} \ (cos(2 \ \alpha)-1)-f_{\pi}^{2}m^{2}_{\pi} cos \ \alpha$$

Where do i go wrong? This should be rather simple, but i have been stuck for way too long.